# Does an email address count as part of a DNS?

Tags: email, dns

Does the part of the email address that is to the left of the @ symbol of an email address still count as part of the DNS?  I've been told it doesn't, but surely it does - it must have it's own unique IP identifier of some sort.

Thanks,

Comment: The local part (left of the @) is completely under control of the servers handling email for the domain part (right of the @). There is no need for global uniqueness nor consistent rules (the left part may or may not be case sensitive, this is up to the servers handling the mail for the specific domain). The right part is used by MUA and MTA to do an MX query in the DNS (and then A/AAAA queries, and sometimes also SPF/DKIM queries, and TLSA ones too), this is the only thing relevant.

Comment: There are various attemps/proposals to put the whole email address in the DNS and a specific record to store for example PGP keys associated with an email.

Answer (score 1):

For more details check [email address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), summarizing:

> The format of email addresses is `local-part@domain` where the local part may be up to 64 characters long and the domain may have a maximum of 255 characters.

The left `local-part` of an email address doesn't count as a part of a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

For the right side, the `@domain`:

> The domain name part of an email address has to conform to strict guidelines: it must match the requirements for a hostname, a list of dot-separated DNS labels, each label being limited to a length of 63 characters and consisting

You could also check the [RFC 2822 - 3.4.1. Addr-spec specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

Sending an email consists of two parts (its actually a little more complicated, but this is the simplified version - ignoring the local to internet part, and ports / encryption etc)

presuming you send an email to someone@example.com

Firstly, the domain name is looked up. `example.com` - the proces for that is that the configured DNS server is queried for an MX record. If the configured DNS server doesn't know, it will bounce the query up to the `.com` domain, to find who owns `example.com` from there it may get bounced up to the `.` root servers. Eventually, a response will come back that might look something like this

```
example.com.    300 IN  MX  1 mx1.example.com.
example.com.    300 IN  MX  2 mx2.example.com.
```

The mail server will then perform another lookup on mx1.example.com, this time obtaining the IP address.

It will then open a session to that IP address, and something like the following conversation will occur.

```
220 mx.example.com ESMTP n14si1330437wmh.246 - gsmtp
ehlo mail.example.com
250-mx.example.com at your service
mail from: me@example.com
250 … OK
rcpt to: test@example.com
250 … OK
```

So for the DNS portion of the process, the `test@` part is never used. A DNS server has no concept of an `@` in that context.

Once the DNS portion is completed, then the whole email address is used with the conversation to the mail server.